# Premature carriage return for my table of contents page

Tags: css

I am using a program (Pressbooks) to publish a book. I am doing a table of contents, with chapters. What I am experiencing is that if a title has so many words, they won't all fit on the one line even though they easily could; the title is split over two lines. I am trying to figure out what setting to change so that the whole title goes on one line.

E.g. instead of

11. The boy goes to school

every day

I would like

11. The boy goes to school every day.

Here is the CSS code that (I believe) is relevant:

```
#toc {
  page-break-before: right;
  counter-reset: part;
  font-family: "Noto Serif", "Georgia", "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
 }

#toc h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

#toc a {
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#toc ul,
#toc li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#toc ul {
  counter-reset: chapter;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

#toc li {
  position: relative;
}

#toc .front-matter,
#toc .back-matter {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

#toc .front-matter .introduction {
  font-style: normal;
}

#toc a::after {
  content: leader(" ") target-counter(attr(href), page);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#toc .front-matter a::after {
  content: leader(" ") target-counter(attr(href), page, lower-roman);
}

#toc .introduction a::after {
  content: leader(" ") target-counter(attr(href), page);
}

#toc .part {
  margin: .5cm 0 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

#toc .part a::before {
  content: "Part " counter(part, upper-roman) ". ";
  counter-increment: part;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#toc .chapter a {
   padding-left: 0px;
}

#toc .chapter {
  margin-top: 0.5cm;
}

#toc .chapter a::before {
  content: counter(chapter) ". ";
  counter-increment: chapter;
  margin-right: 7pt;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#toc .part a::after {
  content: '';
}

#toc span.toc-chapter-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 70%;
}

#toc .chapter + .back-matter {
  margin-top: 1.3em;
}

#toc span.chapter-author,
#toc span.chapter-subtitle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

#toc span.chapter-subtitle {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#toc span.chapter-author {
  font-family: "Alegreya SC", "Libre Baskerville", serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
}

#toc h1 {
  margin-top: 20pt;
}

#toc .front-matter,
#toc .back-matter,
#toc .chapter {
  margin-bottom: 0.2px;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
}

#toc .part {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

#toc .chapter {
  margin-top: 0.15em;
}

#toc .chapter span.chapter-subtitle,
#toc .chapter span.chapter-author {
  margin-left: 20pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know without the html, but you can try to modify the 70% widths to 95 or 100%

```
#toc span.toc-chapter-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Beauty. That changed it. Thanks! As for the HTML, I am a little new at all this and so I'm not entirely sure how to make that happen. Any hints?